# Flutter :-How to put the view in the Center and Bottom of the screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am creating the tutorial screen in which the two views like:-  one is should be in the center of the screen and another should at the bottom of the screen.

But my both view is not proper, please check the below images.
I have done some lines of the code to do it but the not getting the proper solution, please check below code once

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:page_indicator/page_indicator.dart';

    import 'login_screen.dart';

    class Tutorial extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        // TODO: implement createState
        return _TutorialScreen();
      }
    }

    class _TutorialScreen extends State<Tutorial> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child:Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 250.0,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0,top: 40.0,right: 10.0),
                  child: PageIndicatorContainer(
                    pageView: PageView(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.yellow,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    length: 3,
                    align: IndicatorAlign.bottom,
                    indicatorSpace: 5.0,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 80.0,
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: OutlineButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context)
                                .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()));

                          },
                          textColor: Colors.white,
                          child: Text(
                            "Login",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          child:
                          Text("SignUp", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )

              ],

            )

          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Please check above code once and let me know once.

[image]

Comment: you want to make red widget is in center and purple widget in the bottom ? :'D

Comment: @MohamedGaber Color will change, i am creating it for the demo purpose or you can say for learning purpose

Comment: you want to make as i say in first comment or something else because i want to post answer in your question

Comment: Yes the same thing , i want as you commented first :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this to get required view

```
Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Align(alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.redAccent,),),
      Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Container(height: 100, color: Colors.purpleAccent,),)
    ],)
```

Comment: Thanks for input , will let you know soon, Can you please add some explanation on it.

Answer (score 1):

Put the bottom `Container` inside `Align` widget and use `alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter` .:

```
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                    height: 80.0,
                    color: Colors.purple,
                    child: Row(

                    ... .... ... // other code
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **@Zulfiqar** But It is not necessary to put the whole view inside the **`Stack`** widget and use the **`Align`** property with  it.
We can also use the **`Expanded`** or **`flexible`** widget to come out from the problem.

 We can also use the **`MediaQuery`** for it like below

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:page_indicator/page_indicator.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _HomeScreen();
  }
}

class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    super.initState();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
   return Material(
     child:Align(
         alignment: Alignment.center,
         child:Column(
           children: <Widget>[
             Container(
               height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.90,  /////HERE I USED MEDIAQUERY FOR IT
               child: PageIndicatorContainer(
                 child: PageView(
                   children: <Widget>[
                     Container(
                       color: Colors.red,
                     ),
                     Container(
                       color: Colors.yellow,
                     ),
                     Container(
                       color: Colors.blueAccent,
                     )
                   ],
                 ),
                 length: 3,
                 align: IndicatorAlign.bottom,
                 indicatorSpace: 5.0,
                 padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
               ),
             ),
             Container(
               height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.10, ////HERE I USED MEDIAQUERY FOR IT
               color: Colors.purple,
               child: Row(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                 children: <Widget>[
                   Container(
                     child: OutlineButton(
                       onPressed: () {

                       },
                       textColor: Colors.white,
                       child: Text(
                         "Login",
                         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                   Container(
                     margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                     child: RaisedButton(
                       onPressed: () {},
                       color: Colors.black54,
                       child:
                       Text("SignUp", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                     ),
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
             )

           ],

         )

     ),
   );
  }
}
```

And for the `pageView` i have used this library  **page_indicator: ^0.3.0**

And output from above code is as follow 
[image]