# Flutter: Slider Gallery with overflow container

Tags: flutter

I've stuck with one problem.
I'm a novice with a flutter trying to figure out how to do a simple *swipe-left/swipe-right* gallery.

I'm looking for a widget that supports gestures and some kind of overflow.

So I want a container with a fixed(width/height which I can define) and everything outside of this container should be hidden and when user swipes inner content it should show the next slide. Can you please point me out what is the best way to implement this with a **Flutter** and what is the best kind of containers fit these goals. Thanks

**UPD 1:**
It shouldn't be a whole screen, but a specific container.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the `PageView` widget for the viewpager functionality , you can use it horizontal or vertical as your requirement,As you want horizontal `PageView` so i have used the  `scrollDirection:  Axis.horizontal` for it. I have created the demo of it, please check it once

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _HomeScreen();
  }
}

class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {
  static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey =
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  ///Page Controller for the PageView
  final controller = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size _screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Horizontal Viewpager',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
        ),
      ),
      ///A Page View with 3 children
      body: PageView(
        controller: controller,
        scrollDirection:  Axis.horizontal,

      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        pageSnapping: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.lightBlue,
              elevation: 4,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Card 1",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 24),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.purpleAccent,
              elevation: 4,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Card 2",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 24),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.pink,
              elevation: 4,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Card 3",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 24),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And output of above program as follow

[image]

You can check my another example where i have created the swipable with fixed height [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61315342/3946958)

I am posting another example, as you need the indicator at the both side of the `PagewView` for it , you need to use the `Row` with `Expaned` as follow

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _HomeScreen();
  }
}

    class _HomeScreen extends State<HomeScreen> {
      static final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey =
      GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

      var selectedPage = 0;


      PageController _controller = PageController(initialPage: 0, keepPage: true);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Size _screenSize = MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size;
        return Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(
              'Horizontal Viewpager',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
            ),
          ),

          ///A Page View with 3 children
          body: Container(


            child:Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.4,
              child:  Row(
                children: <Widget>[

                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child:
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                      highlightColor: Colors.pink,
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (selectedPage > 0) {
                            selectedPage = selectedPage - 1;
                            _controller.jumpToPage(selectedPage);
                            print("VALUES==>>>>> $selectedPage");
                          }
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ), Expanded(
                    flex: 8,
                    child: PageView(

                      controller: _controller,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),

                      onPageChanged: (index)
                      {
                        selectedPage= index;
                      },
                      pageSnapping: true,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Card(
                            color: Colors.lightBlue,
                            elevation: 4,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Card 1",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 24),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Card(
                            color: Colors.purpleAccent,
                            elevation: 4,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Card 2",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 24),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Card(
                            color: Colors.pink,
                            elevation: 4,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                "Card 3",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 24),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child:
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                      highlightColor: Colors.pink,
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (selectedPage <3) {
                          selectedPage = selectedPage + 1;
                          _controller.jumpToPage(selectedPage);

                          print("VALUES==>> $selectedPage");
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  )

                ],
              ),
            )


           ,

          )

          ,
        );
      }
    }
```

Please check the below output of it 
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ravindra, that's almost what I need. I'm curious, what kind of widget we can use, to hide all content that is outside of the container. Something like this https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/toc23VNzZLL8yhZtAREqrGz8z3puluo_YCoM5JQcmyzLXsXEkUyQPy3TBNshOr6Q2Go=w272 the content will not be visible outside the container.

Comment: Have you checked my another solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/61315342/3946958  ..Let me know in case of concern

Comment: Ok @DmytroFilipenko You just need to use the `Row` widget with `Expanded` like you need to give the weight of the three widget **1**,**8**,**1**,   .     **1*** for the arrows which are side and  **8** for the `pageview` which is in center, Have you get my point..Let me know otherwise i will create the demo for it also

Comment: so, it's should be something like this. https://cloudup.com/cYQpmxWjlhQ is it possible with a `Row`, `Expanded`?

Comment: Ok i am working on https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/toc23VNzZLL8yhZtAREqrGz8z3puluo_YCoM5JQcmyzLXsXEkUyQPy3TBNshOr6Q2Go=w272 , will post the answer soon

Comment: @DmytroFilipenko Now check the solution and let me know in case of concern

Comment: that's what I was looking for. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DmytroFilipenko Happy to help you!! Could you please mind to upvote my answer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61315342/3946958

Comment: Can you please tell me how can we show the children in the PageView if they are dynamic, I do not have static 3 pages, I can have multiple children which will be dynamic, how to add those? @RavindraKushwaha @ DmytroFilipenko

Comment: Yes it can also be possible, but sorry i have not worked on flutter from last 1 year, But i am sure it possible by twinkling above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `carousel_slider 2.1.0` package.

It also has many customisation options.

https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

[image]

[image]